# Is this reasoning reasonable?

Tags: calculus

I wanted to find $$\lim_{x\to 0} 
\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ In Tom Apostol calculus book, I have the function $f(x) = x^{m/n}$ is **continuous** if m, n are positive integers . Knowing this information , I wrote the limit in another form $$\lim _{u\to 1}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{u}}$$ where $u = 1-x^2$ (because I'm not sure $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is continuous ), and then I can solve this immediately. Ok , but the main problem is that I wanted to check this transformation rigorously , so assume two of this limit have the same value , say **A**  for second . Then I define $\varepsilon$ for the second , so base on the definition of Tom Apostol calculus I have a $\delta$ such that if $0 < |u - 1| < \delta$ , or $0 < |x^2| < \delta$ or $0 < |x - 0| < \sqrt{\delta}$ then $|f(x) - A| < \varepsilon$. So this is the same as the terminology generated in the first limit . Actually, I also feel ambiguous when describing , so that is the reason I want to ask you guys .

Comment: Composition of continuous maps is continuous.

Comment: Thanks !! I will meet composition soon ,so I'll know the truth .